# How to find a unique maximum

Tags: r, unique

I have a following data in r:

```
dummyData = c(5,8, 9, 25, 30, 55, 55)

dummyData

sort(dummyData,TRUE)
[1] 55 55 30 25  9  8  5
```

Then, I'd like to find the unique maximum in this list, which is 30. I thought of using "while" or somehow "for loop", but I am not quite sure how. Could someone help me with it?

Comment: Reformatted code segments

Comment: What do you mean by "unique maximum"? Like the maximum after removing numbers that occur more than once?

Comment: yes, exactly.  In my example, the max will be 50 but it's repeated.  I want to choose the max that is not repeated.  In my example, it is 30...

Answer (score 2):

Just filter the vector to remove any duplicated values in addition to *the* duplicated value and then take its max:

```
max(dummyData[! (duplicated(dummyData) | duplicated(dummyData, fromLast = TRUE))])
[1] 30
```

Alternatively, you could leverage `table()`:

```
max(as.numeric(names(which(table(dummyData) == 1))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!.. I really like the table function approach.  So slick!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This feels unnecessarily verbose, but it works (also I guess would want to avoid `sort()` if you have large vectors):

```
dummyData <- c(5, 8, 9, 25, 30, 55, 55)

findUniqueMax <- function(input_vec) {
  found <- FALSE
  ind <- 1
  input_vec <- sort(input_vec, decreasing = TRUE)

  while(!found) {
    if (ind > length(input_vec)) {
      val <- NULL
      found <- TRUE
    } else if (sum(input_vec[ind] == input_vec) > 1) {
      ind <- ind + 1
    } else {
      val <- input_vec[ind]
      found <- TRUE
    }
  }
  return(val)
}

findUniqueMax(dummyData)
```